# sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set [OSX]

Tags: macos

So i was in teamviewer with my newbie developer who was trying to install some node js packages, npm install. he was having some issues with some libraries, he changed the permission of my mac sudo.

All the solutions I'm searching online are mostly related to ubuntu where they are suggesting this
1. Log out as the current user, then log back in as root.
2. Execute chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
3. Log out as root, then log back in as the current user.

which simply doesn't work in mac. any solution other than re-installing?

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [apple.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions. The [help] has more information regarding the types of question that are on-topic here.

Comment: ahh okay i will make an account